# iOS - UIToolbar resized after returning from background

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a toolbar that I've manipulated to take up a bit more screen real estate. The problem is when the app comes back from the background it is re-sized to the stock size and I can't seem to re-size it again.

How I'm currently modifying it is just via `self.naviagtionController.toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(X,Y,W,H);`

Also I'm using the navigationController toolbar. (and I have a very specific reason for using the navigationControllers toolbar)

Comment: when and where are you doing this?

Comment: I've tried it directly on the AppDelegate and I've also tried setting them on the UIViewController, both seem to resize the toolbar to stock dimensions after the App is brought back into the foreground.

Comment: Have you try to do this in your controller's viewWillAppear method?

Comment: Yes, although viewWillAppear isn't called when an App returns to the foreground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your checking for the app became active notification and then setting the toolbar size. You then set a custom size and after you set the size something comes along and changes it back to the default size. Is that about it?

I think there would be a better way to do it, but...

You could try delaying your change till the main run loop executes. You can do this by using GCD to put the action on a background thread which puts it back on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // set toolbar frame
        self.naviagtionController.toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(X,Y,W,H);
    });
});
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work for me... the dispatch_get_main_queue doesn't appear to take those parameters. At least Xcode isn't telling me it doesn't.

Comment: You are correct. I failed at copy and paste. dispatch_get_main_queue takes no params. I left them in when I cut and paste the 2 lines in a row. I fixed the code above.